# Is it possible to provision resources using terraform to an existing Resource Group in Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am attempting to provision an Azure Functions instance and a Cosmos DB instance to an existing resource group. However, in all the documentation I've found, it seems a new resource group is created and the resources are provisioned there. Is it possible to provision the resources to an existing resource group?

Here's one of the links I've been following: https://www.hildeberto.com/2021/03/terraform-azure-function.html

Comment: You can utilize the data module instead of resource to import or incorporate an existing resource group into your configuration. @Thiziri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Provisioning resources using preexisting RG

Yes, it's definitely possible to provision Azure Functions and Cosmos DB instances to an existing resource group using Terraform. You do not need to create a new resource group unless your use case specifically requires it.

use the following configuration I tried for reference purpose till function app you can continue provisioning rest of the configuration using the same hierarchy.

***My terraform configuration:***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Reference an existing Resource Group
data "azurerm_resource_group" "existing" {
  name = "testrg-vk"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "functionsappvksb"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name
  location = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

# Azure Function App Service Plan
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "testvk-asp"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

# Azure Function App
resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                = "testvk-functionapp"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  os_type                    = "linux"
  version                    = "~3"
}
```

***Deployment Succeeded:***

[image]

[image]